# Is there any way to draw on a map with Sikuli?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, sikuli

I'm successfully able to click on particular area on map with the help of Sikuli, but my requirement is to draw on the map via the [Sikuli Webdriver](http://code.google.com/p/sikuli-api/wiki/SikuliWebDriver)

Here is an example of what I want to be able to draw with Sikuli:

[image: How to draw on map view]

Comment: Not sure what is being asked.  Could you provide some more detail?

Comment: I'm in real estate domain, in which i need to draw on map, we have customized the map-v3 so user can search on the basis of location:
I want to draw on map- while using sikuli with removewebdriver- Not able to draw.

Comment: There are two possible interpretations of "draw on map with Sikuli".  You could mean to use Sikuli to draw on the screen over the map. This is useful for demos or debugging to draw the user's attention to something.  Or you could mean to use Sikuli to use the keyboard and mouse to interact with some map program so that the map program draws something.

Comment: your first assumption is correct, need to draw area on map view with mouse, Still wondering for the solution...

Comment: @NimeshPrajapati It's confusing that you said "your first assumption is correct" and then echoed my second statement...  I guess I'll assume you meant my *second* assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the Sikuli webdriver and are looking at the examples for that.  You want to use the webdriver to draw within a map webapp.  This isn't supported, but it is possible (with some hacking). Here are pointers to the pieces you need.

The code to the Sikuli webdriver is [on Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/doubleshow/sikuli-webdriver).  You will want to branch the code and modify `DefaultImageElement`.  Right now, it only knows how to `click()` and `doubleClick()`, but it does have the coordinates of the element, which is what you need.

Next, take a look at Selenium's page on [Advanced User Interaction](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AdvancedUserInteractions).  There's a section "Generating Action Chains" that's what you want.  The documentation only shows things acting on web elements, but there are other methods in the `Actions` class to blindly operate the mouse.

Putting this together, let's say we want to click on **Sign Hill Park** and drag to **On Trac Warehouse**.  This is skeleton code; you'll have to do a bunch of implementation work to get anything running.

Using a new method you wrote

```
ImageElement park = driver.findImageElement(SIGN_HILL_PARK_IMG);
ImageElement warehouse = driver.findImageElement(WAREHOUSE_IMG);
park.dragTo(warehouse)
```

Implementation ideas for `dragTo`:

```
public class DefaultImageElement {
    //...
    public void dragTo(DefaultImageElement dest) {
        Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
        Action dragAction = builder.moveToElement(containerWebElement, x, y)  //containerWebElement is the element that holds the map, x and y are the location of our target within the map
            .clickAndHold()
            .moveToElement(dest.containerWebElement, dest.x, dest.y)
            .release()
            .build();
        dragAction.perform();
    }
    //...
```